# What does "10 minutes away from nursery" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Transcript from [this video](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/uk-england-leeds-47503924/bradford-nursery-some-children-have-not-seen-many-trees?intlink_from_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.com%2Fnews%2Feducation&link_location=live-reporting-map) (min 00:31):

> So when we bring them here, it's a whole new world for them. It doesn't feel like we're just **10 minutes away from nursery**. I think it just sparks their imagination, I think it just sparks their creativity.
>   (Minute 00:31)

Does it mean "they're just allowed to play in the woods for 10 minutes" OR "the distance from the nursery to the woods is just 10 minutes"?

It doesn't feel like we're just 10 minutes away from nursery.

Comment: Can you please provide a transcript of the text to your question? The video may disappear at some time in the future, and the question will not remain understandable. Thank you.

Comment: So when we bring them here, it's a whole new world for them. It doesn't feel like we're just 10 minutes away from nursery.I think it just sparks their imagination, I think it just sparks their creativity.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of the (transcribed) text is:

> Although we are only 10 min away from the nursery, the surroundings are so different that it feels like we are on the other side of the world. Because the world is so different (despite of being so close), it improves their imagination and creativity.

As implied, the 10 minutes refer to the time needed to go from the nursery to the woods (considering the unspecified way to travel - by foot, by car, by bus...).

Answer (score 2):

"Ten minutes away" from somewhere, as a description, means it's a ten minute journey to get from one place to the other. That might be a ten minute walk, it might be a ten minute drive, it might be ten minutes by public transport.

Now, you can talk about *having* ten minutes away from somewhere, and that means spending ten minutes not being there. But *being* ten minutes away, as a description of a place, means the journey time.